# Is it possible to declare an empty function as a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

Is it possible to do something like this, and create an empty function that will later be assignable, because I keep getting an error where i can't call the function that was assigned this is the closest I have gotten

```
fileprivate class actionButton: UIButton{
    var functo = ()
    func tapped(functoCall: () ->Void){
        self.functo()
    }
}
```

this buttons initialized in a function which takes a function as a parameter and passes it on to this button which is a descendent of the class specified above

```
    button.functo = funcToCall()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yes.tapped(functoCall:)), for: .touchDown)
```

the issue i get is when i try to call self.functo() i get cannot call non-function type

Comment: You generally would just define `functo` to be a closure and because it won't have anything yet, it would be an optional, e.g. `var functo: (() -> Void)?`.

Comment: Or, if you don't need to tell if it's `nil`, you could give it a default value of a function that does nothing, e.g `var functo = {}` (and it will be inferred to be a `() -> Void`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

The reason you are getting the error is that the compiler can't know that `functo` is in fact a function that is callable. You made it an `Any` implicitly.

You just have to cast it (using `if let` for example) to a function of the desired type first.

Something like this should get you started:

```
var myfunc: Any = ()

func test() -> String {
    return "Cool"
}
// Assign any function to myfunc
myfunc = test

// Just cast it to the expected type
if let x = myfunc as? ()->String {
    x()
}
```

In case the question is just particular to this problem (as a downvoter thinks) you can just type your variable with the signature of your function. This is the trivial case:

```
var myfunc: ((Any) -> Void)? = nil
```

Then it is callable when you assign it.

Comment: Rather than defining `myfunc` to be `Any`, you should declare it as, using your example,  `() -> String`. That way, no casts are needed.

Comment: My example is contrived. If you can know the signature upfornt, of course you can just store your function in such a typed variable. It was not my impression that that was the problem. My example should illustrate that you can store an arbitrary function in a variable and then call it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know this is going to help you. But I think SwiftUI user's will be helped. You can declare like this

```
var functo: () -> Void
```

If you want to use it in SwiftUI you can pass function from one view to another view like this

```
struct CustomAlertView: View {
    var title: String
    var msg: String

    // Function for execution
    var functo: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title.weight(.semibold))
                .padding(10)
            
            Text(msg)
                .font(.title3.weight(.medium))
        }
    }
}
```

And you can pass function from other View to that view in parameter like this

```
struct NewView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomAlertView(functo: timeTravel)
        }
    }

    func timeTravel() {
        print("Do something")
    }
}
```

Note: If you want to use it as a real alert, use it in ZStack.